# Solved 'ERROR 1054 Unknown column' importing into MariaDB 10.4

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqldump

I recently tried to migrate a database from an old Debian 8, MariaDB 10.1 server to a new Debian 10, MariaDB 10.4 but met with this nasty error

```
ERROR 1054 Unknown column 'pusername' in 'field list'
```

I tried to import the same sql into a Debian 10, MariaDB 10.3 and it imported flawless. I then tried to export dump from this 10.3 and import it in my MariaDB 10.4 but again same exact error as above.

I read alot but could not find what could be causing it.
Any remedies ?
Here is a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out... 
it was an old stale trigger' that was carried over for years.... wonder none of the previous version upto MariaDB 10.3 complained about it.  Removed the trigger from source DB, exported and then ***successfully imported***  into new Server with MariaDB 10.4.12